# Array results are not displayed when I am accessing the array,How can I access specific field values in this array

Tags: php

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( 
      [Bounces] => 1 
      [Complaints] => 0 
      [DeliveryAttempts] => 405 
      [Rejects] => 0 
      [Timestamp] => 2014-11-07T11:47:00Z ) 

        [1] => etc etc
        // Multiple array values are here
     );
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Then take a half hour and reformat it if it will help answer the "question."

Comment: Took me 36 seconds to edit it....dunno what youre talking half an hour for

Comment: so there are arrays with key in an array. tag says php, so if we say that $array equals to all that, than to get Bounces i would make $array[0]['Bounces'] and i am pretty sure it would return me 1

Comment: I answered it, but I still cant tell if its a serious question, or trolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple multidimensional array.

Just do this..

```
 foreach($yourArray as $val){
     foreach($val as $v){
            echo $v['Bounces']."<br>";
            echo $v['Complaints']."<br>"; // etc etc
     }

 }
```

Or if you want to just get values directly without looping

```
 $yourArray[0]['Complaints']; // Complaints attribute of 1st array entry
 $yourArray[1]['Bounces']; // Bounce attribute of 2nd array entry
 $yourArray[4]['Rejects']; //Rejects attribute of 5th array entry
```